# How to get XLS file format value using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have XLS cells deference number formatted. this how look like my cells

[image: Cells of the XLS file]

- E8: Date formatted cell
- E9: Number formatted cell
- E10: General formatted cell
- E11: Percentage formatted cell
- E12: Fraction formatted cell

I want to read these above cells data without any changes(Friday, May 10, 2013 , 41404.00, drfsdf, 1/2) i use below method for that but i didn't success every bellow method return for text value of the cells

```
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file_path);
$rowIterator = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator();

$array_data = array();
foreach ($rowIterator as $row) {
   $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
   $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
   $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex();
   $array_data[$rowIndex] = array('A' => '', 'B' => '');
   foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
    if ('A' == $cell->getColumn()) {
         $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
      } else if ('B' == $cell->getColumn()) {
         $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
      }
   }
}
```

please help to get view value of the XLS file as `Friday, May 10, 2013 , 41404.00, drfsdf, 1/2` in to the $array_data  using PHPExcel.

Comment: You can also use the worksheet's toArray() method to eliminate the need for your row and cell iterator loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the

```
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

otherwise PHPExcel has no way of knowing whether a cell is formatted as a date or not

setReadDataOnly(true) tells PHPExcel to load **only** the raw data from each cell. As the only way MS Excel differentiates a date/time from a float is through the number format mask (not from the raw data), and you're telling PHPExcel not to read the number format masks, PHPExcel can't tell the diference, so all floats are simply treated as floats

Comment: i removed `setReadDataOnly(true);` and read data as $cell->getFormattedValue();. that is ok with every Date formatted cell except 5/10/2013 that read as 05-10-13

Comment: If your date formatted cell containing 5/10/2013 is using a locale-format mask, then PHPExcel can only display it as a general date using a default date mask because it isn't locale-aware... but you are still getting the value converted to a date format

Comment: Is that possible to over write default date mask and get real value form the cell(that mean read  5/10/2013 without any changes)?

Comment: No.... MS Excel does __not__ store dates in cells. It stores a floating point value, and it's only the number format mask that identifies that as a date, and gives some guidelines on how to display it. The "real value" in the cell is a float value of 41552. The number format mask used identifies it as a locale-specific date, and PHPExcel dutifully formats it as a date; but as PHPExcel is unaware of the locale it cannot use the exact format that MS Excel uses, because the exact format that MS Excel uses varies depending on who is viewing the file (based on their country)

Comment: Unless you know which cells contain dates, and set the date format mask yourself to a format that you choose before reading the cell's formatted value

Comment: is that possible to PHPExcel check which cell contain dates?

Comment: is that possible to read if cell is format as Date(sort/long or any other date format) that cell read as date and else that cell(cell format text/number etc not Date) read as string

Comment: If you've used `setReadDataOnly(true);` then no, it isn't possible to distinguish between date/times and other floats. The only difference is the formatmask, and `setReadDataOnly(true);` suppresses reading that information... if `setReadDataOnly(false);` then `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime()` can be used to test if a cell contains a date/time value, or methods like `getFormattedValue()` or `getCalculatedValue()` will return a formatted date string

Comment: Thanks for your feed back. `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime()` this what i need. PHPExcel is great library. thanks for develop open source library

Comment: I love this open source library. I have little confuse with date format again. i set as `setReadDataOnly(false);` and try to read Excel date cells `4/30/1910` => '3773', `4/30/2010` => `40298` that two date have deference float vale as above. i read that cells date as `$cell->getFormattedValue()` but that two cells give as same date as 04-30-10 please explain why happen

Comment: @Duleep - That all depends on the date numberFormat mask that's been applied to the cell: if the format only displays two digits of the year, then the two dates would look identical