# PHPExcel: formattedValue() returns dates in "dd/mm/yyyy" format instead of custom "yyyy-mm-dd" as defined in the .xls/.xlsx files

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am working on a system that needs to accept Excel files (.xls as well as .xlsx files), these files consist of several columns: `date`, `location`, `time`, etc.

The `date` and `time` cells are formatted as how the user wants it to formatted. The `date` format could be `dd-mm-yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` and the `time` format could be `h:mm` or `hh:mm:ss`. Of course any other format is allowed, as long as Excel accepts it.

This means I need to use the `$cell->getFormattedValue()` method in order to get the values I need, because I need the values as how they are formatted by the user. But here is the catch.

For some reason the date is always returned in the `dd/mm/yyyy` format. I tested this with the Excel5 and Excel2007 reader, but they both give the same result. In the uploaded Excel sheet the formats are `dd-mm-yyyy`. I also used `$cell->getStyle()->getNumberFormat()->getFormatCode()` to check what format is used and that is returning `dd/mm/yyyy;@`, not corresponding with the uploaded file.

I have the exact same problem with the `time` column, my defined format is `hh:mm` but it returns the values in the `h:mm` format.

I thought about a regex to check if it is a date or time and change the format accordingly, but I guess this isn't normal behaviour as I didn't find anything about this on the internet. I have found a lot of topics about people not getting their data correctly formatted, but that is due to the `setReadDataOnly()` method on the reader, which isn't the case here as I get formatted results, but in the wrong format. I have also tried the `toArray()` method on the complete sheet, but that also returns the dates formatted the wrong way.

Any thoughts on why the Excel reader is converting all the dates to some sort of default date format/mask?

If it is necessary I can use this standard, but then I need to understand if this is programmed behaviour or if it is a bug. Because if it is a bug, I can not rely on this output every single time, if it is programmed I can. But if it is programmed, how can I get the real getFormattedValue for when I need that?

---

ps. It has similarities with [How to get XLS file format value using PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046704/how-to-get-xls-file-format-value-using-phpexcel) but that is not the case here. I get the formattedValue, but in the wrong date format. When I use `getValue()` I even get a number instead of a date, so the formatting mask is working.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603451/phpexcel-get-formatted-date-as-is-visible-in-excel-file

Comment: Hey Mark, thank you for the quick reply. But no, I already use the `getFormattedValue()` method. When I use `getValue()` I get an integer (at least for the date column), so that is not the case :)

Comment: You should get an float (not an integer) if you use getValue().... the point is that getFormattedValue() uses the number format mask to render a formatted date/time string; but it can't render locale-specific format masks because it isn't locale aware, so uses a default format

Comment: The answer I provided there also tells how to identify if a cell contains a date/time value, and how to convert that float to either a Unix timestamp or to a PHP DateTime object that can then be formatted using standard PHP functions.... without any need for using a regexp for anything

Comment: So if I understand it correctly getFormattedValue() will never output dates in the format as provided in the Excel? If it recognises a date, it will always use `dd/mm/yyyy`? Because if I look at the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603451/phpexcel-get-formatted-date-as-is-visible-in-excel-file I would suspect it to output it in the format provided. Or is the format there, not considered "locale-specific"? So I can not say, lets use `dd-mm-yyyy` in Excel and use that in PHPExcel?

Comment: About the integer/float thing of the date, an integer is correct in this particular case as the time is not present in the date column. https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Convert-dates-stored-as-text-to-dates-8df7663e-98e6-4295-96e4-32a67ec0a680 cite: "Excel stores dates as sequential serial numbers so that they can be used in calculations. By default, January 1, 1900, is serial number 1, and January 1, 2008, is serial number 39448 because it is 39,448 days after January 1, 1900."

Comment: No, `getFormattedValue() ` will work perfectly well with many date formats; but ___some___ date "formats" in MS Excel are flagged as locale-specific, and their format will vary depending on the locale settings of the PC where they are being displayed.... these locale-specific formats are flagged with a `*` in the MS Excel GUI number format selector for dates/times

Comment: And technically, a date is still a float `39,448` will actually be `39,448.0`

Comment: I understand the local-specific part, I did some research this morning (about the asterisk), but "dd-mm-yyyy" is not local specific as it is not flagged with an asterisk, so it does not depend on the settings of the PC. I tried it with some other formats and they don't work either. Have you given it a try yourself? Might it be possible there is a bug in 1.8.1? If it works on your computer then it should have to do something with my Excel sheet, which I think is the case, but I can not figure out what since the date format is `dd-mm-yyyy` and not the `*dd-mm-yyyy`preset (note the asterisk)

Comment: It's highly unlikely (although not completely impossible) that there is a date formatting bug..... but I'd need a lot more proof that this is actually a bug in PHPExcel (especially as I can't replicate it).... on average, I spend/waste nearly 9 hours each week searching for bugs that have been reported, but that aren't actually bugs.

Comment: And yes, I have given it a try.... I'm even working on fixing a bug triggered by date formatting, but that's related to quoted text within the format mask

Comment: I understand that completetly and you have my respect Mr. Baker ;-). Is it possible to send you an Excel file over the mail to see if you have the same problem? Then we can be sure what causes the problem. If you agree with that I will send you an email at the address found on your Github profile page.

Comment: No problem, it's a lot easier to identify any problem with a working example